# Fixed heading hiding body elements in fluid layout

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am working on a fluid layout (using all percentages and no pixels) and have a fixed heading (#heading) at the top of the page. I want all elements of the rest of the site to start at the *bottom* of the heading and not disappear under it as the user scrolls down.

I researched this problem, but the only solution I could find was to add padding to the top of the site's main content that is equal to the height of the heading. This solution was, to my knowledge, mostly applicable to pixels because they won't behave differently in different browser window sizes or resolutions.

I tried this, but the problem is that because I'm using percentages and not pixels, the solution doesn't work when the browser window is made smaller. When I shrink the browser window, the top of the main content still disappears under the heading. I'd be grateful for any pointers.

This is the browser window at normal size:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNMRW.jpg)

This is the browser window decreased in size:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1chc.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="heading">
<div id="name">
   <img src="logo.svg" width=100%>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a> <a href="portfolio_start.html">PORTFOLIO</a> <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a> <a href="resume.html">RESUME</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="site_content">
    <div id="side_panel_portfolio">
    <a href="portfolio_illustration.html">Illustration</a><br>
    <a href="portfolio_gd.html">Graphic Design</a> <br>
    <a href="portfolio_web.html">Web Design</a>
    </div>

    <div class="divider">
    </div> 

    <div id="mygallery">
    <!--(the images)-->
    </div>

    </div> <!--End of #site_content-->

    </div> <!--End of #wrap-->
```

CSS:

```
body {height:100%;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:1.3vmax;}
#heading{height:14%;
    width:100%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    top:0;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-left:0;
    Padding-right:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;}
#site_content{padding-top:6.7%;
        z-index:99;
        height:100%;}
#side_panel_portfolio{float:left;
    padding-left:3%;
    position:fixed;}
#mygallery{float:right;
        width:79%;
        padding-right:%;
        padding-left:3%;}
#portfolio_start{padding-left:18%;}
.divider{position:fixed;
    left:15%;
    top:14.7%;
    bottom:40%;
    border-left:1px solid black;}
```

Basically, I want #site_content to start at the bottom of #heading and #mygallery to be the only div that can scroll.
Sorry for the long question!!

*Also just want to say that I'm using another artist's work as thumbnails purely for the development process as placeholders and that site is NOT online and will not be online with those images.

Comment: Where are your media queries?

Comment: I'm pretty new to web design so, embarrassingly, I forgot media queries were even an option. I don't know much about them. But are you suggesting I just use those? If you are, I can just research tutorials for that on my own.

Comment: Yes, they are a must for building fluid design sites

Answer (score 0):

Use a div for the logo image to be responsive

```
#logo {
display:block;
width:100%;
```

}

```
<div id="logo">
  <img src="logo.svg">
</div>
```

also do you have all current media queries in your css?
[Device Specific CSS Media Queries Collection](https://gist.github.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c)

Comment: I just added that CSS to my site, but I'm not sure how to use it yet.

Comment: View your site on different devices or use an emulator to check http://browsershots.org/  and also there are 5 testers on http://www.shoutmeloud.com/free-responsive-website-testing-tools-to-test-responsiveness.html

Comment: I just thought for a min. Did you mean you don't know how to use the media queries? Copy all the css from the raw source here and paste the entire thing to the bottom of your existing css stylesheet. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c/raw/f5e6961faf05e923848c61a5e1e7488ec4fef83c/mediaqueries.css

Comment: I have a resolution/device emulator I use and am aware that my site doesn't respond very well (as in the original question) but I haven't yet figured out how to use the media queries to solve this. That's probably up to me to figure out, but thank you for the helpful links.

Comment: I did copy/paste the media queries you linked me to into my css stylesheet, but I'm assuming I'm still missing some piece of the puzzle since it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site online? or upload what you have somewhere so I can see the entire thing?

Comment: Yes, although my university's server (which I'm uploading to for now) doesn't like SVG files and some parts of jquery/javascript so for now I'll just stick to working on this page: http://tiger.towson.edu/~klivel2/365/portfolio_lively/portfolio_illustration.html

Comment: Change your logo image code to like how I posted the code above. Copy that css into your aestetc css sheet and then bombine all of the css stylesheets into 1 to start. Copy the code from justifiedGallery.css, then the justifiedGallery.css and lightbox.css, and mediaqueries.Paste them one by one onto you aesthetic.css and save. You can then delete all the extra href lines to the other css sheets. Keep the aestetic css and link to the google fonts.

Comment: Okay, I did that. Seems to have gone smoothly.

Comment: Your body css has 'body {height:100%; but no width. Here is a stylesheet for one of my charity sites http://www.ahepadistrict9.org/styles.css look and it and copy or change what you need

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks so much for your time and help!

Comment: I saw your change in css. It works good. I would still do the logo image like I suggested. Did you minimize your browser window and watch how your page now resizes? :D

Comment: Yes, it is fluid and technically resizes for small browser windows and devices, but the top of the main content is still cut off when it's minimized. I'll probably follow your logo suggestion--for now I'm just trying to resolve this issue. It's been driving me mad but I'm glad to get help!

Comment: another thing, the justified gallery works but when you click the image it opens full, with a a close option, so you have to manually go back. I really like this one that opens the smaller images in a modal window, all resposive. http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_testing/grid-img-modal-popup-rwd.htm   look at this page I made to see how the logo heder works, that is the code I gave you originally  http://www.ahepa215.org/

Comment: That may be because I only added the lightbox code to the first three images in the gallery. Those do open in a lightbox/modal window. The rest don't yet.

Comment: are those your drawings? very talented

Comment: No, as stated in the original post, those are just placeholders. Off topic I guess, but this is my work (currently hosted in tumblr...hence the need to build my own site!) http://livelyillustration.tumblr.com/